# jQuery validation is duplicating else statements | Values won't print once validation is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

So I am validating a form - The validation works fine but if the user was to get something wrong it would `.after` a `<p></p>` error message. But if the user were to click the `button` more than once it will keep printing out that `.after` error message!

I have tried everything - This includes putting a boolean expression in the if statement and once the `.after` error message prints it will make that expression `false`so the if statement won't run again. This did not work for me.

### I also can't get the values to print out once the validation is all done!?

To try and fix this I have wrapped tried to wrap the validation in  an `if` statement that tests to see if the validation is `true` and then at the bottom of the `if` statement after the `validation` I make that `boolean` value turn to `false` and then I have an else statement which prints out the `values` for each input...This won't work for me!

### jQuery:

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Submit the form for validation
$('#submit').click(function () 
{



        //Get the values from input fields:
        $name = $('#txtName').val();
        $age = $('#numAge').val();
        //Sex:
        $sex = $('sex').val();
        //Email:
        $email = $('#txtEmail').val();
        $confirmEmail = $('#txtConfirmEmail').val();

        //Checkbox
        $("input[name='interest']:checked").each(function() {
                $gender += "" + $(this).val() + ", ";
        });

        //Fish varieties:
        $varieties = $('#txtVariety').val();

        //Put checkbox values into an Array
        var values = $('input:[name="interest[]"]:checked').map(function () {
            return this.value;
    }).get(); 

        //printDetails is the id to print out to.
    for(var i=0; i<values.length;i++){
                alert(values[i]);

    }

    //Start Validation
        if($name.length < 5){
                $('#txtName').focus();  
                $('#txtName').val("");
                $('#txtName').after("<p id='after1' style='color:red;'><strong>Enter a name greater than 5 letters!</strong></p>");
                return false;
            }
            else{
                $('p').remove('#after1');   
                $name = $('#txtName').val();

            }
            if($age.length > 105 || $age.length < 1){
                $('#numAge').focus();   
                $('#numAge').val("");
                $('#numAge').after("<p id='after2' style='color:red;'><strong>Enter an Age less than 106 and greater than 0!</strong></p>");
                return false;
            }
            else{
                $('p').remove('#after2');

            }

            function isValidEmailAddress($email) {
                var pattern = new RegExp(/^[+a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i);
                // alert( pattern.test(emailAddress) );
                return pattern.test($email);
    };
        if(!isValidEmailAddress($email)){
            $('#txtEmail').focus();
            $('#txtEmail').after("<p id='after3' style='color:red;'><strong>Enter a valid email - <span style='color:#0078ab;'>"+ $email +"</span> - Is not valid</strong></p>");
            $('#txtEmail').val(""); 
            return false;

        }
        else{
            $('p').remove('#after3');   
            //Now check if the email is successfully confirmed
                if($email != $confirmEmail){
                    $('#txtConfirmEmail').focus();
                    $('#txtConfirmEmail').after("<p id='after4' style='color:red;'><strong>Your email - <span style='color:#0078ab;'>"+ $confirmEmail +"</span> - Does not match!</strong></p>");
                    $('#txtConfirmEmail').val("");  
                    return false;
                }
                else{
                    $('p').remove('#after4');
                }

            }

        //Check if there is atleast 1 checkbox checked
        if($('input[type=checkbox:checked').length < 1) {
            $('#checkboxError').html('<p id="after5" style="color:red;" id="after5">Please check atleast one checkbox</p>');
            return false;
        }
        else{
            //This should remove the above error message! 
            $('p').remove('#after5');
        }

    //These won't work?
    document.getElementById("printDetails").innerHTML = $name + $age + $gender + $sex + $varieties + $email;
    $("#printDetails").html("<div>" + $name + $age + $gender + $sex + $varieties + $email + " </div");


}); //END OF ONCLICK




}); //End of document.ready
```

### Html

```
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Register jQuery</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">

    <!-- Name, Age -->
      <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="txtName">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="txtName" id="txtName" value=""  />
      </div>
      <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="numAge">Age:</label>
        <input type="number" name="numAge" id="numAge" value=""  />
      </div>

      <!-- Sex, Default value = Male-->
      <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
          <legend>Sex</legend>
          <input type="radio" name="sex" id="sex_male" value=""  />
          <label for="sex_male">Male</label>
          <input type="radio" name="sex" id="sex_female" value="" checked='checked' />
          <label for="sex_female">Female</label>
        </fieldset>
      </div>

      <!-- Emails -->
      <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="txtEmail">e-mail:</label>
        <input type="email" name="txtEmail" id="txtEmail" value=""  />
      </div>
      <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="txtConfirmEmail">Confirm e-mail:</label>
        <input type="email" name="txtConfirmEmail" id="txtConfirmEmail" value=""  />
      </div>

      <!-- Interest In checkboxes -->
      <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
          <legend>I am interested in the following</legend>
          <input type="checkbox" name="interest[]" value='Comet' id="interest_0" class="custom" value="" />
          <label for="interest_0">Comet</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="interest[]" value='Common Goldfish' id="interest_1" class="custom" value="" />
          <label for="interest_1">Common Goldfish</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="interest[]" id="interest_2" class="custom" value="Black Moor" />
          <label for="interest_2">Black Moor</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="interest[]" value='Celestial Eye' id="interest_3" class="custom" value="" />
          <label for="interest_3">Celestial Eye</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="interest[]" value='Fantail' id="interest_4" class="custom" value="" />
          <label for="interest_4">Fantail</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="interest[]" value='Lionchu' id="interest_5" class="custom" value="" />
          <label for="interest_5">Lionchu</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="interest[]" value='Other'  id="interest_6" class="custom" value="" />
          <label for="interest_6">Other</label>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
      <div data-role="fieldcontain" class='display'>
        <label for="txtVariety">Fish Varieties:</label>
        <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="txtVariety" id="txtVariety"></textarea>
      </div>
                <p id='checkboxError'></p>


      <!-- Text Area - Fish Varieties -->


      <!-- Drop down select menu - How did u hear about us -->
      <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="selectmenu" class="select">How did you hear about us?:</label>
        <select name="selectmenu" id="selectmenu">
          <option value="Internet">Internet</option>
          <option value="Email">Email</option>
          <option value="Friend">Friend</option>
          <option value="Billboard">Billboard</option>
          <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <!-- Register & Start again buttons -->
      <input type="submit" id='submit' value="Register"/>
      <input type="submit" id='resetForm' value="Start Again" />
        <!-- Print out the details -->      
        <div id='printDetails'></div>
```

I Have a feeling this code should work - Hopefully someone sees the problem i',

Comment: I think it may be easier to give all your `<p>` validation messages a class like `<p class="errMsg">`. Then on the form submit click just do `$('.errMsg').remove();`. This will remove every error message and then be added back if they fail again. It would help clean up some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so after going through your fiddle and I think I got it working with bare minimum code changes.

The main thing was setting up the boolean `isValid` at the beginning of the submit button event to `true` and setting to `false` when it fails a validation test. Then only displaying your output when the form is valid.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7g0fw34f/)

Also, some jQuery selectors were incorrect and I think there is some confusion between gender and sex. They are the same thing, just different words.

There are still is lots of room for improvement but this looks like a homework assignment so I can tell you maybe still learning.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out how to fix one of the issues - The issue I fixed is the duplication of the `.after` error messages. To fix this I just added  `$('p').remove('#after5');` inside each if statement before the `if` statement actually prints the `.after` error message out.

```
if($('input[type=checkbox:checked').length < 1) {
                $('p').remove('#after5');
            $('#checkboxError').html('<p id="after5" style="color:red;" id="after5">Please check atleast one checkbox</p>');
            return false;
        }
        else{
            //This should remove the above error message! 
            $('p').remove('#after5');
        }
```

### I am still having problems printing out the data when all the validation is correct!

Comment: var values = $('input:[name="interest[]"]:checked').map(function () { should be:  $("input[name='interest']:checked").map(function() {...

Comment: This is not the problem, I have an array of checkboxes in my html. The problem I face now is printing all the details out after all the validation is done!! I can't find out how to do this? @nevermind

Comment: Is there a css style that could be hiding the `<div id="printDetails">`? Can you inspect the DOM and see if anything is getting put inside that div?

Comment: No there isn't @zgood But i'm trying to find a way to print my details out once all the validation has been done! E.g Once all the fields are complete the code should then print the values out. Printing out the values is not the problem here, it's printing them out once all the validation is done that's the problem

Comment: oh I unserdtand now. Can you make a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)? I can help you fix it if you can get a fiddle demostrating your problem

Comment: thank you. I will give it a look through and see if I can find any issues